# datatables-editable plugin doesn't work after dynamically adding row in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jeditable

I creates datatables using:

```
 $('#purForm').dataTable({
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bFilter": false

    });
```

and then for editing I used datatables editable plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/EditCell

So, basically for making it editable I do:

```
$('#purForm').dataTable().makeEditable({
        sUpdateURL: function (value, settings) {
            return (value);
        }
    });
```

After making editable I am trying to add a row dynamically using:

```
 $('#purForm').dataTable().fnAddData(['', '', '', '', '', '']);
```

But the editable is not working for this dynamically added row and which is understandable because it may not be using live api of Jquery. How do I correct this so that it works even for dynamically added rows?

A quick and dirty hack would be again call the function:

```
$('#purForm').dataTable().makeEditable({
            sUpdateURL: function (value, settings) {
                return (value);
            }
        });
```

Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug. Using the Jeditable library with datatables, new rows cannot be added using the fnAddData() function.

The bug report is here:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/issues/detail?id=57

The author doesn't seem to think this is a bug and doesn't really provide any useful help other than to copy the functionality of a seemingly complex private function. If you would like to see an easier method available, then I highly suggest you leave a comment on the bug to inform the author.

FYI, to add a new row and have it be editable, you will need to create a custom form and then submit the row data through fields in the form. See instructions here:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/AddingNewRecords